# How can I remove a resource from terraform state?

Tags: terraform

I am using terraform to manage IaC on AWS. There was a s3 bucket created by my terraform project and later I moved the s3 bucket terraform to a different project. So I deleted all s3 related code in my project. When I run `terraform apply` I get an error saying `Error: error deleting S3 Bucket (xxxx): BucketNotEmpty: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty`

I understand that terraform tries to delete the bucket since I removed the code from there.

I tried to use `terraform refresh` but got forbidden error: `Error: Forbidden: Forbidden
    status code: 403, request id: 8351F9C3663AF8FB, host id:`.

I know I can delete the terraform state file from local but this requires me to import all resources. How can I solve this issue? I am using local state not remote state.

Comment: You can review the resources before remove using [dry run](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/rm#dry-run) : `terraform state rm -dry-run <name>`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

First you need to remove  the resource from the state file by running `terraform state rm <resource-id>` and then you need to delete the associated configuration from your codebase. After that run `init`, `plan` and you will see no changes are required

Comment: As stated on another answer, you can alternatively use the name instead of the id

Answer (score 139):

You can remove any resource added to your Terraform like this:

1. List all state:
   `terraform state list`
2. Remove desired resource from state:
   `terraform state rm <name>`

Answer (score 23):

1. List states

   ```
   $ terraform state list

   data.terraform_remote_state.rg

   azurerm_subnet.vsubnet

   azurerm_virtual_network.vnet
   ```
2. Remove selected state.

   ```
   $ terraform state rm azurerm_subnet.vsubnet

   Removed azurerm_subnet.vsubnet

   Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
   ```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove ALL resources from state file run:

```
terraform state rm -dry-run $(terraform state list)
```

Remove `-dry-run` afterwards for changes to apply.

Answer (score 7):

Couple of things i would like to add,

1. while running the terraform command to remove a resource from the state, make sure you quote(`'`) the resource id appropriately like so,

```
terraform state rm 'module.s3.module.s3_bucket["my-s3-bucket-name"].aws_s3_bucket.this[0]'
```

Looks silly but, I cannot believe, I just wasted the last 10 minutes scratching my head on this.

2. Terraform state list can often be very long. If you need to remove a group of resources sharing a common name you can use the following bash oneliner,

```
terraform state rm $(terraform state list | grep production-files)
```

For example, the command above will remove a aws_s3_bucket, aws_s3_bucket_policy, aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration and so on.

3. Utilize the `-dry-run` flag before performing a potentially destructive operation like this.

```
terraform state rm 'resource_id' -dry-run
```

Output:

```
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Would remove module.s3.module.s3_bucket["production-files"].aws_s3_bucket.this[0]
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

Comment: Super useful hint on quote(').

Answer (score 3):

After some searching I found the solution is to use `terraform state rm` to remove the s3 resource from my local state file.

Answer (score 2):

1. List the resources in the state. `terraform state list`
2. Remove the resource from the state. `terraform state rm '<resource_name>'`
3. Remove the resource definition from the codebase.
4. Terraform apply should show no changes.