# Terraform AKS error: services "azure-vote-back" already exists, how to deal with it?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

In Terraform I wrote a resource that deploys to AKS. I want to apply the terraform changes multiple times, but don't want to have the error below. The system automatically needs to detect whether the resource already exists / is identical. Currently it shows me 'already exists', but I don't want it to fail. Any suggestions how I can fix this issue?

```
│ Error: services "azure-vote-back" already exists
│
│   with kubernetes_service.example2,
│   on main.tf line 91, in resource "kubernetes_service" "example2":
│   91: resource "kubernetes_service" "example2" {
```

```json
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "kubernetescluster"
  resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config[0].host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "azurevote" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "azurevote-annotation"
    }

    labels = {
      mylabel = "azurevote-value"
    }

    name = "azurevote"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-front"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.example.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 80
      target_port = 80
    }

    type = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-front"
    labels = {
      app = "azure-vote-front"
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
        image = "mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1"
        name  = "front"
        env {
          name = "REDIS"
          value = "azure-vote-back"
        }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_pod" "example2" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-back"
    namespace = "azure-vote"
    labels = {
      app = "azure-vote-back"
    }
  }

  spec {
    container {
        image = "mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8"
        name  = "back"
        env {
          name = "ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD"
          value = "yes"
        }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "example2" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-vote-back"
    namespace = "azure-vote"
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_pod.example2.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    session_affinity = "ClientIP"
    port {
      port        = 6379
      target_port = 6379
    }

    type = "ClusterIP"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats the ugly thing with deploying thing inside Kubernetes with terraform....you will meet this nice errors from time to time and thats why it is not recommended to do it :/

You could try to just [remove the record from the state file](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm):

`terraform state rm 'kubernetes_service.example2'`

Terraform now will no longer track this record and the good thing **it will not be deleted** on the remote system.

On the next run terraform then will recognise that this resource exists on the remote system and add the record to the state.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add a bit to @[Philip Welz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16776451/philip-welz)'s answer.

> The `terraform state rm` command is used to remove items from the [Terraform state](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Terraform.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs/state/index.html). This command can remove single resources, single instances of a resource, entire modules, and more. [1]

(Just in case) To list all state:

```
terraform state list
```

According to the documentation, exactly as @[Philip Welz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16776451/philip-welz) mentioned, this command will cause Terraform to "forget" all of the instances of the `kubernetes_service` resource named "example2:

> ```
> terraform state rm 'kubernetes_service.example2'
> ```

After all you should see:

```java
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
```

---

See also links:

[1]  [Doc about Command: state rm](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Terraform.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs/commands/state/rm.html)

[2] [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61297480/how-can-i-remove-a-resource-from-terraform-state)

[3] [This guide](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360061290134-How-to-Remove-Resources-in-a-Remote-State-File-Managed-by-Terraform-Cloud)