# How to set and retrieve variable value for condition in YAML Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The condition on "Deploy_Infrastructure" is using the variable isInfraCreated. The value of isInfraCreated keeps returning 'unknown', even though the PowerShell script sets the values. What am I doing wrong here?

```yaml
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: development
  variables:
    isInfraCreated: "unknown"
    aksClusterName: "bla-aks"
    aksResourceGroup: "bla-aks-resources-01"
  jobs:
  - job: Prepare
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Azure PowerShell: Determine isInfraCreated'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'myAzureSubscription'
        scriptType: 'pscore'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          $aksResource = az aks show --name $(aksClusterName) --resource-group $(aksResourceGroup)
          $aksResource
          if ($aksResource -eq $null)
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isInfraCreated]$false"
            $isInfraCreated = $false
            $env:isInfraCreated = $false
          }
          else 
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isInfraCreated]$true"
            $isInfraCreated = $true
            $env:isInfraCreated = $true
          }
  - job: Deploy_AKS_Infrastructure 
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isInfraCreated, 'False'))
```

Comment: Variables do not persist across jobs. Is there a reason you want to check if the cluster exists? Ideally, this would be automatically handled by your infrastructure-as-code tooling (i.e. Terraform, ARM/Bicep).

Comment: Terraform doesn't handle this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343007/terraform-aks-error-services-azure-vote-back-already-exists-how-to-deal-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set and retrieve variable value for condition in YAML Pipelines?

To resolve this issue, we need to [share variables across jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks) by using output variables from tasks:

> - To reference a variable from a different task within the same job,    use TASK.VARIABLE.
> - **To reference a variable from a task from a different job, use    dependencies.JOB.outputs['TASK.VARIABLE']**.

So, we need update the scripts to:

```
trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: development
  variables:
    isInfraCreated: "unknown"
    aksClusterName: "bla-aks"
    aksResourceGroup: "bla-aks-resources-01"
  jobs:
  - job: Prepare
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Azure PowerShell: Determine isInfraCreated'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'myAzureSubscription'
        scriptType: 'pscore'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          $aksResource = az aks show --name $(aksClusterName) --resource-group $(aksResourceGroup)
          $aksResource
          if ($aksResource -eq $null)
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isInfraCreated;isOutput=true]$false"
            $isInfraCreated = $false
            $env:isInfraCreated = $false
          }
          else 
          {
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isInfraCreated;isOutput=true]$true"
            $isInfraCreated = $true
            $env:isInfraCreated = $true
          }
      name: SetIsInfraCreated

  - job: Deploy_AKS_Infrastructure 
    variables:
      TestisInfraCreated: $[ dependencies.Prepare.outputs['SetIsInfraCreated.isInfraCreated'] ]
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.TestisInfraCreated, 'False'))
```

You could check the document [How to pass variables in Azure Pipelines YAML tasks](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/how-to-pass-variables-in-azure-pipelines-yaml-tasks-5c81c5d31763) for some more details.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the problem but I believe that the syntax for condition of the last job should be like this :

```
- job: Deploy_AKS_Infrastructure 
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isInfraCreated, false))
```